# How to unlock Samsung Galaxy Note 4 from Verizon?

Tags: sim-unlocking, verizon

I bought Samsung Galaxy Note 4 on eBay. It's a Verizon phone. The description said clean IMEI and not blacklisted per Swappa.

I was trying to get it on my Cricket account which is a GSM carrier, but my wireless company said it was locked.

How do I unlock it?

Comment: I bet the eBay description didn't say "oem carrier unlocked"... which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert your Cricket SIM card, check whether it prompts for an unlock code or not. If it does, you can use a third party website like [UnlockRadar.com](https://www.unlockradar.com). But if it doesn't, there's not much that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to double-check if it's really a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 from Verizon because it should be automatically unlocked to use with Cricket.

If your model number is anything other than Verizon, then you need to unlock the phone. Not all phones will ask for unlock code, only for those AT&T and Cricket. But if the phone is T-Mobile or Sprint, the best way to unlock it is by far via USB remote cable.

You can use third-party websites like [miliunlocks.com](https://miliunlocks.com) to unlock it, they unlocked the phone for me in under 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get unlock code. You need to give imei number and sim company name Verizon. You can contact Verizon. Verizon give you code. They check mobile details. You have contract with Verizon.
Pay due money to company. They can give you code.